# JRuby: import vs include vs java_import vs include_class

Tags: ruby, jruby

why so many different ways to include Java classes into JRuby? What are the differences? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find quite a few examples about working with Java classes at:
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

It states, that you should use `java_import` instead of `import` due to the [JRUBY-3171](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3171)  bug.
Also `include_class` is or will be deprecated ([JRUBY-3797](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3797)) in favor of `java_import`.

Currently `java_import` is the recommended way to import a Java class.

Comment: FYI: the up-to-date URL to follow is: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Comment: What about `java_require` ?

Answer (score 13):

`import` doesn't play well with Rake, so it's discouraged. `java_import` is the newest, and recommended. `include_class` has been deprecated. Apart from that they all do the same thing, and are actually aliases of each other.

`import` is an alias for `java_import` and `java_import` calls `include_class`.

Comment: If I read this answer yesterday, I'd wouldn't have wasted a day today!