# Using Custom Java Class file in Jruby

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

I am trying to execute some custom Java code through the latest version of Jruby (1.5.1), Ruby 1.8.7, with Java 1.6.0_06. I have tried both the class file and putting it in a jar method. When I try

```
require 'java'  
require 'path_to_class/myClass
```

or

```
require 'java'  
require 'path_to_jar/a_jar.jar
```

Trying both methods, I cannot access the myClass nor any other files in the jar file. Other variations on the net for importing java classes lead to the following error:

```
`NameError: cannot load Java class com.package.myClass from C:/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/javasupport/java.rb:51:in method_missing`
```

I have also checked the solutions on StackOverFlow and I still get the same outcome. I am wondering if this might be a problem at a deeper level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of 'require', you want 'java_import'.

```
require 'java'
java_import com.package.MyClass
```

See [JRuby: import vs include vs java_import vs include_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578582/jruby-import-vs-include-vs-java-import-vs-include-class) for some more discussion e.g. why you should use 'java_import' instead of just 'import'

Comment: this solution still doesn't work for me. Do I need to compile the custom class in some way to make it load?

Comment: I added some more examples to that wiki link, in case helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Java class `com.mypackage.MyClass` in the same folder, or in a folder present on the classpath, you can call it from your JRuby script like this:

```
require 'java'
import com.pack.MyClass

myClass = MyClass.new
```

If the class is in a jar, you have to `require` the jar:

```
require 'java'
require '/path/to/myjar.jar'
import com.pack.MyClass

myClass = MyClass.new
```

If `myjar.jar` is on the classpath, you can just use `require 'myjar.jar'`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `include Java`?

See this for more details: http://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby

Answer (score 0):

So Here is what worked for me, I had all required stuff that people suggested but what I really needed was

```
$CLASSPATH << (Rails.root.to_s + "/path/to/dotClassFolder")
```

before the java_import statement

so in the file system, if your class was was in the folder

```
Rails.root/path/to/dotClassFolder/folder/anotherFolder/MyClass.class
```

Include     `$CLASSPATH << (Rails.root.to_s + "/path/to/dotClassFolder")`
then        `java_import "folder.anotherFolder.MyClass"`

See

**From .class files** section at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby